# Stackoverflow image uploader

Tags: php, jquery

There is an awesome image uploader in stackoverflow. Im looking for a tutorial for creating application like this with php and jquery.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) ([tutorial](http://www.cagintranet.com/archive/how-to-implement-uploadify-into-an-application/)).

Answer (score 1):

Just a note of caution, my experince with uploadify is that it works great in a demo page, but when you add some complexity to the site, strange things start to happen, small seemingly unrelated changes to your site cause it to stop working unexpectedly in ways that can't be caught through unit testing.

For example, I just clicked the upload button to try to add an image to this post and I couldn't get it to work, nothing happens when I click browse. StackOverflow's developers know what they're doing; I'm sure this passed all StackOverflow's unit tests, and might have worked on their staging site. It could be my browser, who knows, but it doesn't work and if I was the average customer, I'd be blaming the developer.

I've had much better luck with jquery.forms.

Comment: add image in a post is exactly what I want. Is this plugin that you mean? : http://jquery.malsup.com/form/ Thanks

Comment: Yes, I had a popup on my site for uploading images and I got uploadify working, seemed fine, then one day I looked at it again and it just stopped working. This happened several time and while I was able to get it working again each time I was just too nervous about deploying it to a customer.